# OneR and area under the ROC curve

Tags: roc, sensitivity-specificity

In the book Data Mining, author Ian Witten says that it does not make sense to calculate the area under the ROC curve when applying OneR because it finds only one point (sensitivity, specificity) which draws a triangle , not a curve. This is not clear to me.
If  OneR creates a rule on a numerical variable then it may find different values for both sensitivity and specificity and therefore a real curve. Opinions? Thanks